# SELECT from SQL inside for loop

Tags: sql, for-loop, razor, foreach

I'm trying to get some multiplied values from the database from each date where there is a value, like this!

```
var sumKG = 0;
DateTime nextDay;
//Just a random date for test purposes.
var inputDate = "2016-12-27";

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{

    var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = '" + inputDate + "'"; 

    foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
    {
        //This is the calculation that I want.
        var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;

        //These three rows are date related and add 1 day to
        //inputDate which is used above in the SQL query line.
        DateTime thisDay = c.date;
        nextDay = thisDay.AddDays(1);
        inputDate = nextDay.ToString("dd/MM/yy");

        //This gives the total of the calculations done in each foreach loop.
        sumKG += total;
    }
    @sumKG <br />
}
```

So what I want from this is that when the `foreach` has done its thing which each row in the database that in this case is dated "2016-12-27" it should then change the `inputDate` to "2016-12-28" and run the `foreach` again for each row dated with that new date.

However, while the sql query is inside the `for loop` this does not work, I get the error:

`The data type is not valid for the boolean operation.`

Im not sure what to do about this? Because in my mind the sql query has to be inside the `for loop` else it wont be able to get the new value of `inputDate`?

Any suggestions? (not MVC project)

Comment: try to change inputDate =  nextDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Damn! Didn't really think that would do anything, but actually worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following thing and then i should work..

```
inputDate = nextDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```